# Docker: Could not find any MySQL database drivers. (MySQLi or PDO required.)

Tags: php, mysql, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to customize a default PHP image to develop a wordpress plugin locally

This the docker-compose.yml section about wordpress service

```
  wordpress:
    container_name: wordpress
    build: actual-wordpress
    #image: php:5.5-apache
    volumes:
      -  ./actual-wordpress/www/:/var/www/html/
      -  ./actual-wordpress/wp-config-local.php:/var/www/html/wp-config.php
      -  ./actual-wordpress/srtool/:/var/www/html/srtool/
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    restart: always
```

And this is the 'actual-wordpress' dockerfile being builded

```
FROM php:5.5-apache

RUN apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends php5-gd php5-mysql
```

As you can see, I manually install `php5-gd php5-mysql`

When I run the container, I got this error

```
Fatal error in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php, line 1570. Call to undefined function mysql_connect()
Could not find any MySQL database drivers. (MySQLi or PDO required.)
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: It think it's impossible to know for sure what a given PHP package contains just by name, esp. if you don't even know the distro being used, but I suspect you need to install PDO or mysqli explicitly.

Comment: I'm sure that PDO is included into php5-mysql package... but I'm not able to find php.ini into my docker container. I used ` find / -name "*.ini"` but no php.ini found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

docker-php-ext-install mysql mysqli pdo pdo_mysql