# Dockerized Symfony 5 app error "An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver"

Tags: php, mysql, docker, symfony, debian

I'm learning Docker so I tried to dockerize an old proyect I made a little ago, it is a Symfony 5 app, its like a shop app so it uses a mysql database.

I have the following docker compose

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  php:
    build: 
        context: .
        dockerfile: docker/build/php/Dockerfile
    ports: 
        - "9090:80"

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment: 
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:-root}
```

Now, inside `docker/build/php/Dockerfile`

```
FROM php:7.3.3-apache

COPY . /var/www/html
```

When I build the image and then run `docker-compose up` it all seems to work fine, when I go to `localhost:9090` I get an error about permissions so I run `chmod -R 777 var` inside the php-apache container to fix it, I refresh the page then I got `An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver`

Searching on google I found several solutions that says something like I need to run this command to fix it

> sudo apt-get install php7.2-mysql

When I run that this happens

> E: Unable to locate package php7.2-mysql
>
> E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.2-mysql'
>
> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2-mysql'

Or this one

> apt-get install php-mysql

This throws this error

> Package 'php-mysql' has no installation candidate

Any other command about installing something throws an error like one of the two from above, how can I fix this driver error?

There are some info about my container

```
root@a15f68bd3605:/# cat /etc/*-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

```
root@a15f68bd3605:/# uname -a
Linux a15f68bd3605 4.19.76-linuxkit #1 SMP Tue May 26 11:42:35 UTC 2020 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This is my .env from the symfony project

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/popcollector?serverVersion=5.7
```

Comment: What is your DATABASE_URL in .env file? Just change your confidential info before posting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker Laravel Mysql: could not find driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56759646/docker-laravel-mysql-could-not-find-driver)

Comment: Hi @AlexanderDimitrov I just edited my question

Comment: @Leprechaun Thx for ur comment, I already tried that, it didn't worked for me

Comment: I just noticed, the DATABASE_URL must be changed to work inside a container enviroment, right? I must know what the mysql container ip is to change my .env before building the docker compose, is that right? is has nothing to do with the driver not found error since if my symfony project could make a connection then it would throw another error. This will eventually will cause me another error 

Comment: @H3lltronik you should replace 127.0.0.1 with mysql. 127.0.0.1 refers to the php container and you don’t have the dB engine there.

Answer (score 7):

You need to enable the `pdo_mysql` extension in the container.
You can do that by adding this line to your Dockerfile:

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
```

Answer (score -2):

in general it is a bad practice to install software inside a container afterwards. make sure to use the correct container in first place.

you can use the webdevops container for example. To use that, simply replace the line `FROM php:7.3.3-apache` in your Dockerfile with `FROM webdevops/php:debian-8-php7`

More info about the webdevops container on https://github.com/webdevops/Dockerfile

Comment: It’s quite normal to install software to a container which you use as a base image.

Comment: Hi, Thx for ur response. I did that, then when I go to localhost:9090 all I get is a ```ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE```

Comment: I noticed that you don't have a password in you DATABASE_URL. Or was that just a typo?